# Pulling two different sets of data from the same document library in a single page SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint

I have a document library set up with multiple different categories of document, and I'm using a metadata column to differentiate between them.

I want to be able to display two different document library web part on a page for different categories of file side by side.  This is simple for one category, I just set up a list view filtered by the metadata column, but when I add a second web part alongside the first, it breaks the first one.

I have no idea why this is happening, but it seems like SharePoint isn't happy with pulling two sets of data from the same document library.

When I am editing the web parts, I can get them to both display the documents I want, but then when I click save, the first web part empties.

Not sure what other information would be useful for diagnosing or helping with the problem, so if I haven't given enough detail let me know.  I am familiar with SPD as well as developing through the web interface, so if this needs a more complex solution that's fine with me!

Comment: SharePoint is quite capable of doing what you're asking. Here are some questions that might help you find the solution: You're not copy-pasting your existing web part I hope, since that would cause problems like you're describing; you should twice use the button to add a new web part. If that's not it, try creating a new page and adding your library twice to that page to see if the problem persists; if it solves your problem, the easiest solution might be to delete and recreate whatever page you're working on. If those don't work, bring your question over to sharepoint.stackexchange.com!

Comment: I went through those steps when I was trying to figure out the problem initially, the same thing happened on a different page when I tried the same thing.  I also encountered the same problem when I tried to do this with a different document library.

Answer (score 0):

Having spent some more time playing around with this, it struck me that I could probably achieve what I wanted using something other than a Document web part, and I was right.

Instead of using the somewhat inflexible document web part, I created a content query web part which only searched within the document library from my site, and filtered by the metadata column.

This way I can create as many queries as I like and they don't interact with each other in weird ways.  It also has the advantage of being significantly easier to customise the output without needing to resort to SharePoint Designer.

Content Queries are the answer!